# App stops working on firebase signup button clicked

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am using firebase in my android application and I tried to create a signup button and when ever I click on the signup button, the app crashes with the following error in my console

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.olar.lapitchatkotlin, PID: 8327
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdf)' on a null object reference
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.olar.lapitchatkotlin.RegisterActivity.regCreateBtnClicked(RegisterActivity.kt:45)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

This is my code for the sign up are shown below with my xml file and RegisterActivity.kt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="regCreateBtnClicked"
        android:text="Create account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/regUsername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/regEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/regPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regEmail" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my kotlin file

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}

public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = mAuth?.currentUser

}

fun regCreateBtnClicked(view: View): Unit {

    val username = regUsername.text.toString()
    val email = regEmail.text.toString()
    val password = regPassword.text.toString()

    mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
}

private fun registerUser(username: String, email: String, password: String) {
    mAuth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)?.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = mAuth?.currentUser
            updateUI(user)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            updateUI(null)
        }
    }
}

private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {

    val mainIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(mainIntent)
    finish()
}
```

}

Comment: added. the stack trace

Comment: I have added the error code

Comment: Where did you make connections between `views` and `ids` for example:
`regUsername  = findViewById(R.id. regUsername) as TextView`

Comment: since I am using kotlin, i dont have to explicitly define those terms

Comment: Please add the content of your both `build.gradle` files and responde with @.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in either one of the following 3 lines:

```
val username = regUsername.text.toString()
val email = regEmail.text.toString()
val password = regPassword.text.toString()
```

You need to make sure all the variables you are using exists before calling `regCreateBtnClicked`.

Comment: how do I do that please, I do not seem to understand

Comment: Just debug your code :) If you don't know how to do it, check this link: https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%201/31_c_the_android_studio_debugger.html

Comment: I do not think it is the textfields. I put in hard codded strings in the function and I still got the crash after commenting out the textfields. but if I comment out the signup function and make a toast with the inputed text, it shows the toast with the parameters